# Add new column to existing SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I've created an SSIS package using the Import/Export Wizard - it involves several tables with some of the original columns dropped(). It seems like I 'ignored' one too many columns, but I can't figure out how to get it back. When I go to edit the mappings, I can see the column name on the left, but not on the destination table. Any idea how to fix this without rebuilding the package?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSIS validates package metadata often, and as such, it automatically notifies You whether You have to refresh source/destination metadata or not. (or maybe you have turned Work-Offline option on, in this case turn it off)

This leads me to conclusion that You instructed import/export wizard to make package create destination table if it does not exist. Since that column was not generated in the destination database at the moment of the first package execution, you will never see any new column in the destination. You have to manually add column to destination table in database (watch out for data type, collation, ... column should be the same as in source). Then package will recognize that column.

Answer (score 1):

^^^

On your destination server, you need to add the ignored column(s) to the table. Then when you go back into the mapping, the column will be available on the destination table.

```
ALTER TABLE
    dbo.MySemiReplicatedTable
ADD
    IForgotThisDamnColumn varchar(35) NULL
```